# Cant Get into DSL modem's Config page

Tags: adsl

I have been given an modem by Reliance communications.

Its a Binatone ADSL+ modem.

Now I have changed my ISP ,but want to use Binatone DSL modem with my new ISP.

Problem is i cannot open 192.168.1.1 even if I reset the modem.

Is the modem locked by previous ISP or I m missing something?

Only if i can get into config page i can handle further.

Any guide?

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct IP address? If you are physically connected directly to the modem, try looking at your gateway address and web to that, it is probably the modem.

Comment: @acejavelin Yes that IP is mentioned on back of modem itself, but it wont open though. I tried a direct connection as well as via wifi router